# Reference for multivariate orthogonal polynomials

Tags: reference-request, polynomials

I want to learn about multivariate orthogonal polynomials. Is there a good textbook/survey that you could suggest?  I need to see common examples like Jack's polynomials etc .. and also general theorems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for representation-theoretical polynomials (Such as Jack, Macdonald, Schur), or of other types (Chebyshev, Koornwinder, Laguerre)?

Comment: I don't know apriori. If there would be  reference(s) to learn basics of both that would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only book fully dedicated to the topic seems to be "Orthogonal Polynomials of Several Variables", by Charles F. Dunkl and Yuan Xu.
Cambridge University Press,  2001

Comment: I recommend this also.

Comment: I've started looking at it and it looks like a good book so far. Thanks!